# MyBatis configuration with spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

this is the first time i'm using stack overflow but because i can't find an answer.

I'm trying to connect to my data base using myBatis with spring on java, but the documentation that i find is confusing and not very clear. Do someone knows an useful link to learn that?

Comment: What about this example ? http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mybatis-integration-example/

Comment: that one seems useful, i'll check it, but a doubt that i always have is how the structure is made. Because i find examples with maven projects, web applications, java projects, etc. And i don't know which type of project should i make with eclipse.